# MYSQL Select Distinct with SUM

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

I am developing a Stocks management application, the Portfolio register table has 4 columns, other than date and registry_key, and it looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------
| stock_key | user_key | units | price |
----------------------------------------
| fund_a    | user_1   | 1000  | 100.35|
| fund_c    | user_2   | 4000  | 101.55|
| fund_d    | user_3   | 2000  | 105.65|
| fund_a    | user_1   | 1500  | 101.45|
| fund_b    | user_1   | 500   | 103.35|
----------------------------------------
```

I wish to select the portfolio of user_1 with distinct stock_key. Plus I need the price as the aggregate total paid over the number of units. For example:

For user_1 the result should be:

```
[ 
    {fund_key: "fund_a", units: sum(1000,1500), price: sum(1000*100.35,1500*101.45)/sum(1000,1500)},
    {fund_key: "fund_b", units: 500, price: 103.35}
]
```

This is important because once the user has brought more units of the same stock at a lower/higher price than before, the accumulated stocks price is averaged out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query:

```
    SELECT 
        concat("fund_key: ",stock_key,", units: ",sum(units),", price: ",round(sum(units*price)/sum(units),2)) as result
    FROM PRUEBA.new_table2
    GROUP BY stock_key,user_key;
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, this might help

```
SELECT 
     stock_key "FUND_KEY",
     SUM(units) "UNITS",
     SUM(units * price) / SUM(units) "PRICE"
FROM
     stock_mngmt_app
WHERE
     USER_KEY = 'user_1'
GROUP BY STOCK_KEY
```

Comment: You can remove `USER_KEY` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Lennart yes and that would be less costly as well. Thanks btw.